# Not getting a static IP for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, networking, networkmanager

I'm not sure what I am missing to have my static IP??

Here are my network configuration files:

`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.2 puppet master
192.168.1.3 agent1 machine1
192.168.1.4 agent2 machine2
192.168.1.5 agent3 machine3
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
# Created by anaconda
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=agent1
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

The primary interface's config file, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
UUID=9b49c161-f7b4-418d-ae5f-a4fae294d302
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=no
IPADDR=192.168.1.3
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=192.168.1.1
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

And here is the output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:84:c2:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 85698sec preferred_lft 85698sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe84:c2b6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:18:f1:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.99.100/24 brd 192.168.99.255 scope global dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 996sec preferred_lft 996sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe18:f1a8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:44:89:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I have verified that I am connected to the internet with a `ping` command.

This is the latest configuration as of now.

```
 [root@agent1 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
    ; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
    search netgear
    nameserver 192.168.1.1
    [root@agent1 ~]# ping -c 5 google.com
    ping: unknown host google.com
    [root@agent1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 
    TYPE=Ethernet
    BOOTPROTO=static
    DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
    IPV6INIT=yes
    IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
    IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    [b]NAME=enp0s3[/b]
    UUID=9b49c161-f7b4-418d-ae5f-a4fae294d302
    [b]DEVICE=enp0s3[/b]
    [b]ONBOOT=yes
    NM_CONTROLLED=NO[/b]
    IPADDR=192.168.1.3
    PREFIX=32
    GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
    DNS1=192.168.1.1
    IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
    IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
    [root@agent1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
    # Created by anaconda
    NETWORKING=yes
    NETWORKING_IPV6=no
    GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
    [root@agent1 ~]# ip addr
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:84:c2:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet [b]192.168.1.3[/b]/32 brd 192.168.1.3 scope global enp0s3
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe84:c2b6/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:18:f1:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
        link/ether 52:54:00:44:89:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 500
        link/ether 52:54:00:44:89:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    [root@agent1 ~]#
```

Please note that this is all on VirtualBox installed on Windows 10. I have two  network adapters Adapter 1 Bridege andAdapter 2 Host only.

I am hoping that this information helps us to identify and solve the problem.

Comment: `enp0s3` is the name of the device, not `eth0`, right? You might want to check your configuration again.

Comment: I am quiet confident that it is enp0s3 for eth0. I am not sure why funny names in CentOS 7. I think eth0 for my CentOS 6.8 virtual machine

Comment: The funny names are new method for naming devices so the same device is much more likely to get the same name every time. Not sure whether it changed between those CentOS versions but it could be and therefore you need to adapt your configs.

Comment: Pretty much everyone says to update ifcfg-enp0s3 file with static ip and restart network and NetworkManager.
I did the following:
Change Name  to enp0s3 and Device to enp0s3 in ifcfg-enp0s3 file from eth0
1. Restarted network and NetworkManager

Couldn't get to internet and therefore type in dhclient and I could get on internet and got IP for enp0s3 but still not static meaning the one defined in ifcfg-enp0s3 file.

Comment: @learner:  You'll need to start over as saying you did something and it didn't work which is why you went backward doesn't help you move forward.  Show us what you think should be the proper configuration so we can point you in the right direction as what you show is obviously wrong since it refers to `eth0`.

Comment: @phk: [Consistent Network Device Naming](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html) first appeared in CentOS 6 as a feature that was only used in certain configurations. In CentOS 7, you pretty much have to explicitly turn it off if you want to avoid using it.

Comment: I believe I have static IP now but no connection to internet.

I read [url]https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44838[/url] that for static IP we don't need NetworkManager and dhcp so I uninstalled it using 

yum remove dhclient NetworkManager
reboot

As of now, if I type dhclient I do not get get connected to internet which I was before. That is right as I have "uninstalled" dhcp package.

However I believe I have static IP but no connection to outside world.

Comment: Does your ifcfg-enp0s3 file really have `[b]` and `[/b]` in it?

Answer (score 1):

Put your nameserver in `resolve.conf` to `8.8.8.8`

edit your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

```
ONBOOT=no  
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=eth0
```

to the below

```
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
```

`systemctl restart network.service`

Comment: Its already there, check my post again. I edited with current configuration which had enp0s3 as the name of Device and Name. If I put nameserver as 8.8.8.8 in resolve.conf it gets overwritten to name of Router address which is 192.168.1.1

Comment: So have you mentioned your static IP in the config file.

Comment: Yes mate. Static IP in ifcfg-enp0s3 file. I have updated DNS IP the one I got from my internet provide. DNS1 and DNS2 in ifcfg-enp0s3 file + they are now in resolv.conf file. Still no connection to internet.

Comment: To whomsoever this may concern.

This is not duplicate thread.

Issue was it was single host network. Also the link which you have provides uses old Centos commands(Pre 7 release)  in CentOS 7 service is not used.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1189123

Comment: Also we don't have to anything in /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/sysconfig/network Everything is just one file. Also this is not duplicate. Issue was with network mask which no one could direct me to